# How do I close a collapsible jQuery tab with a link or when a form is submitted?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs

I've set up vertical tabs where people can put in info before they submit a form.

The problem is that people might not find it intuitive to click on the tab again to collapse it.

How do I add a "close" link within the tab and how do I have any open tab close when the user hits "submit" or "reset"?

Answer (score 0):

Simple&Easy way:

Add some css class to every 'window' when you open it. You are already opening those sliding windows so this shouldn't be a problem. Then when that submit button is pressed, you just find element with that class and hide it (display:none / slide back / .. whatever) + remove that class.

There are of course more complicated and more elegant ways how do it. It depends on your needs and situation.

Comment: I'm sure you're right, but I'm not enough of a programmer to take it from there.  As Homer Simpson would say, could you dumb it down a shade?  I want the link inside the tab to behave the same way as clicking on the tab button itself.  So it needs to hide the open tab and change the color of the button back to normal.